# Open-source IoT platform for telemetry collection

Tags: open-source, iot

I'm looking for an open-source platform able to collect telemetry from devices and provides:

- Customizable dashboards for collected data
- Manage multiple facilities and capability to aggregate devices on each facility
- Historical data visualization
- Capability to send alarms

Comment: What protocols do you have/need?

Comment: We are pretty open to any protocols, since we are planning to develop our sensors's software and or gateway. Also, data will be sent through internet using a GPRS modem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, I've been analyzing [Thingsboard](https://thingsboard.io) which:

- Supports MQTT, CoAP out of the box
- Extensible widget library
- Drill down dashboards
- An optional Gateway that can be used to integrate legacy devices

Comment: That looks very good. Did you go with it in the end? If so, you can accept your own answer, which will help others in future.